# Restore Outlook 2013 Emails That Weren't Synced?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, backup, sync, imap

Recently migrated from a webhost email account to Rackspace. The company owner's email account was apparently not syncing this whole time, nor were the files local (somehow.)

All changes he's made to his email account have been lost. Almost a year of important emails have been deleted when outlook decided that the local emails didn't need to be uploaded to the new server. He has no restore points on the computer and his Carbonite backup apparently had quit working a long time ago.

Is it possible to restore these in any way? I'm not holding out much hope, but I'm hoping one of you has some miracle solution.

Comment: Ahh... sync failures. I wish you luck, or a strong beverage.

Comment: Yeah it's looking like strong beverages at this point. Hopefully I can spin this into a lesson about how important backup systems are.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook stores mailbox PST files at `C:\Users\user\Documents\Outlook Files` (on Windows 7 and Outlook 2010, at least).  Depending on how the migration was performed, you may still have the old mailbox file with local copies of the email.

Check there for other PST files.  If the upgrade was done by File->Info->Add Account, there may be a different PST file still there. In the future, make sure that location is included in your next Carbonite backup!

Other locations of preference files, address books, and so on are available here: [Where does Microsoft Outlook 2010 save my information and configurations?](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Where-does-Microsoft-Outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-e178f6d6-1515-4c7e-8202-6c7f4794c0a3).  Good luck!